# ¿Cómo generar un bucle para cambiar nombres de columna?

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo una base de datos con diversas columnas, y necesito cambiarle los nombres  idealmente en un bucle para que el código no quede tan gigante, estos son los nombres de mi base de datos

```
names(df)
[1] "names"                 "ANYO_PROCESO"         "SITUACION_POSTULANTE" "COD_CARRERA_PREF_01"  "ESTADO_PREF_01"      
 [6] "PTJE_PREF_01"         "LUGAR_PREF_01"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_01"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_02"  "ESTADO_PREF_02"      
[11] "PTJE_PREF_02"         "LUGAR_PREF_02"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_02"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_03"  "ESTADO_PREF_03"      
[16] "PTJE_PREF_03"         "LUGAR_PREF_03"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_03"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_04"  "ESTADO_PREF_04"      
[21] "PTJE_PREF_04"         "LUGAR_PREF_04"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_04"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_05"  "ESTADO_PREF_05"      
[26] "PTJE_PREF_05"         "LUGAR_PREF_05"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_05"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_06"  "ESTADO_PREF_06"      
[31] "PTJE_PREF_06"         "LUGAR_PREF_06"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_06"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_07"  "ESTADO_PREF_07"      
[36] "PTJE_PREF_07"         "LUGAR_PREF_07"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_07"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_08"  "ESTADO_PREF_08"      
[41] "PTJE_PREF_08"         "LUGAR_PREF_08"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_08"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_09"  "ESTADO_PREF_09"      
[46] "PTJE_PREF_09"         "LUGAR_PREF_09"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_09"    "COD_CARRERA_PREF_10"  "ESTADO_PREF_10"      
[51] "PTJE_PREF_10"         "LUGAR_PREF_10"        "POND_ACAD_PREF_10"
```

entonces me gustaría generar un bucle en el que para cada nombre que se repita y solo cambie el número, quitándole el primer digito a los nombres. por ejemplo que `PTJE_PREF_01` pase a `PTJE_PREF_1` y así sucesivamente.
Lo que quiero evitar es generar 50 renames 1 a 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por que un bucle si R ya maneja operaciones vectoriales de forma nativa?

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("_0", "_", colnames(df))
```

Con `gsub` remplazamos el `_0` por `_` quitando el 0 al comienzo.

Comment: mil gracias, funcionó super.